# Editing php.ini file

Tags: php, html, ftp

I'm using phpinfo to find out where the server's **php.ini** file is located:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

When I log-onto the server using FTP, I don't see it in the path under **Loaded Configuration File**.

1. How can I download/edit the php.ini file?
2. Can I create a custom php.ini file for one directory (and its sub directories), so that the global PHP settings are not changed?

Comment: the ftp user probably does not have the required permission. depending on hosting you may never be able to edit the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

probably you don't have permissions to view the file.
what you can do is make a `custom_settings.php` and use `ini_set()` to change the configurations and include that file where ever need, to change the configuration settings.
Please refer to https://www.php.net/ini_set

Answer (score -1):

If you have Direct Admin installed, you can login as admin and edit it there.

Answer (score -1):

It should be on location

```
/etc/php.ini
```

If not found there, you can search it by using

```
locate php.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change any values​​, try to do it in .htaccess file

Examples:

```
php_flag   display_errors       Off
php_value  upload_max_filesize  2M
php_value  error_reporting      0
php_flag   magic_quotes_gpc     Off
```

Comment: My script works perfectly in production but not the development environment. I'm assuming it's because the php settings are different. Without knowing the root cause of the problem, I simply want to take the php.ini file in production and apply it in the directory that contains the script on dev.

Comment: Via SSH

An alternate way to download your php.ini file would be to connect via SSH as the Server Administrator.

Change directory to the etc folder using this command:

'cd ~/../../etc'
Use the following command to start editing:

'vi php.ini'
Copy the contents of the file